# How to write a kotlin flow/coroutine that will delay up to a certain amount of time, but can be signaled early to continue

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a flow that will emit the given authentication state, and if authenticated it will delay until the expected expiration before looping again. If unauthenticated it waits some max amount of time (maybe 30 seconds or so) and then loops again. However I'd like this to work such that from externally the repo can get a "refresh" call which will cancel any pending delay (and thus loop again). In java land without coroutines this is fairly easy with things like wait/signal or CountdownLatch. I'm not sure how to implement this properly with coroutines though. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sealed class AuthState {
    object UnAuthenticated: AuthState()
    data class Authenticated(val expirationDate: Date): AuthState()
}

class AuthRepo {
   fun getAuthFlow(): Flow<AuthState> = flow {
    
       while(currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
           val expireDate = authData.getAuthExpirationDate()
           val now = Date()
           if (expireDate.before(now)) {
              emit(AuthState.UnAuthenticated)
           } else {
              emit(AuthState.Authenticated(expireDate))
           }

           val delayAmt = if (expireDate.before(now)) MAX_DELAY else now.time - expire.time
           delay(delayAmt)
       }
   }

   fun refresh() {
      //called from outside when authenticated/unauthenticated, I want the coroutine to cancel any delay here. 
   }


}
```

Comment: Please note each call to `getAuthFlow()` starts a separate flow. Do you want `refresh()` to resume all of them? it feels like it should be a state flow instead.

Comment: Potentially yeah. But perhaps this should just be a hot flow? Not really familiar with building flows. I just want my UI to be able to collect the latest state and make changes if that state is updated..

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to command a flow to be doing something on demand, this will probably have to involve a hot flow.

Here's a possible (untested) strategy, using a MutableSharedFlow that allows your public flow to also listen for manual refresh requests while waiting for the delay. You can still expose the public flow as cold if you like, so you don't have to create a CoroutineScope for the repo that has to be managed with its lifecycle.

```
class AuthRepo {
   private val refreshRequests = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(extraBufferCapacity = 1)

   val authFlow: Flow<AuthState> = flow {
       while(true) {
           val expireDate = authData.getAuthExpirationDate()
           val now = Date()
           val delayAmount =
               if (expireDate < now) {
                  emit(AuthState.UnAuthenticated)
                  MAX_DELAY
               } else {
                  emit(AuthState.Authenticated(expireDate))
                  expire.time - now.time
               }

           val delayFlow = flow {
               delay(delayAmount)
               emit(Unit)
           }
           // Suspends until first emission by either flow:
           merge(refreshRequests, delayFlow).first() 
       }
   }

   fun refresh() {
      refreshRequests.tryEmit(Unit)
   }

}
```

Comment: But as mentioned in @broot's comment, this probably does make more sense conceptually to be a hot flow.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly but I haven't figured out why. It seems to always delay the delayAmount and not complete the refreshRequests flow first..

Comment: What happens if you give the MutableSharedFlow constructor an `extraReplayBuffer` of 1 or 2?

Comment: i trued bumping the replay and extra buffer (to 1 and 2 both) with no luck..

Comment: `extraBufferCapacity` does need to be 1, I think to handle the single collector under the hood of the `merge` operator. I'm not sure what else would make it fail. I got a sample working with code similar to the above. https://pastebin.com/gjMhaxZ7